# ASP.NET MVC viewmodel SQL query syntax

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, action, viewmodel

I'm trying to convert basic models to model vİew and SQL queries. So what is wrong my queries or other files?

```
// GET: Cars
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<CarsTrxViewModel> model = db.Database.SqlQuery<CarsTrxViewModel>(SqlCars.CarsTrxByID()).ToList();

    return View(model);
    // return View(db.Cars.ToList());
}
```

View model:

```
public class CarsTrxViewModel
{
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public string CarBrand { get; set; }
    public string CarModel { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}")]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Query:

```
public static class SqlCars
{
    public static string CarsTrxByID()
    {
        return "select " + " * , " +
             "cars.CarID as CarID " +
            ",cars.CarBrand as CarBrand " +
            ",cars.CarModel as CarModel " +
            ",cars.CreateDate as CreateDate " +
            "from (SELECT * from [NagisOfflineDB].[dbo].[cars] )";
    }

    public static string GetCardholderByID()
    {
        return "SELECT TOP 1 * from [NagisOfflineDB].[dbo].[cars]";
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Cars
{
    [Key]
    public int CarID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string CarBrand { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string CarModel { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not join or other operations I'm just select one column in one table and set alias rows so what is wrong my query?

> Compiler say your query wrong its error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ')'.'

Full version of error

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 20:
>   Line 21:
>   Line 22:             List model = db.Database.SqlQuery(SqlCars.CarsTrxByID()).ToList();

And the stack trace

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near ')'.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +2552942
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5952492
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +285
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4169
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +58
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +89
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted) +430
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +2598
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) +1483
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +64
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +240
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +41
>      System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) +14
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +402
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +166
>      System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryInternal(String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters) +266
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass69`1.<ExecuteStoreQueryReliably>b__68() +44
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +288
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass69`1.<ExecuteStoreQueryReliably>b__67() +167
>      System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +190
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryReliably(String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters) +462
>      System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery(String commandText, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters) +60
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass14`1.<ExecuteSqlQuery>b__13() +130
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +45
>      System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +387
>      System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
>      NgsOfflineDev.Controllers.CarsController.Index() in C:\Dev\NagisDevOffline\NgsOfflineDev\NgsOfflineDev\Controllers\CarsController.cs:22
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +61
>      System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>      System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__0() +58
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +228
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +35
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9874329
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159

Version Information:

- Microsoft .NET Framework Version: 4.0.30319
- ASP.NET Version: 4.7.3062.0

Comment: What happened when you run the same query in SQL management studio?

Comment: What if you change the query to `select * from cars`?

Comment: ım need set allias my rows so ı cant use select * from cars ı cant run this query on sql managemen studio   my query is  select * , 
                 cars.CarID as CarID 
                ,cars.CarBrand as CarBrand 
                ,cars.CarModel as CarModel 
                ,cars.CreateDate as CreateDate 
                from (SELECT * from [NagisOfflineDB].[dbo].[cars]      and sytnax error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'cars'.
 can u fıx this query ?

Comment: Why not just `SELECT CarID, CarBrand, CarModel, CreateDate FROM [NagisOfflineDB].[dbo].[cars];` ?

Comment: if ı change         public static string CarsTrxByID()
        {
            return " SELECT CarID, CarBrand, CarModel, CreateDate FROM [NagisOfflineDB].[dbo].[cars]";     give this error    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'NagisOfflineDB.dbo.cars'.' because of ım try to iterate my objects can you check my question again  sqlcars file pls

Comment: The original error is about a syntax error. It's because you haven't aliased the `SELECT` that's in the parentheses. If you fix that, you'll get the *"Invalid object name"* error again. In the end, you're missing either the table or permissions to it. The simpler query showed that. Keep the query. ***Fix the availability of the object*** on the server.

Comment: @MehmetBaşaran  "Invalid object name" means the table does not exists in the [NagisOfflineDB] database and/or under dbo schema. Could you verify your database whether the table exists under dbo schema in [NagisOfflineDB] database? Next thing I would check is whether MVC application is hitting correct database or not? Pelase post your observations here.